# Arraylist to JLabel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to print arraylist contents into Jlabel but the problem is that it only shows the last integer I add, if somebody can help me please?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        jLabel1.setText(list.toString());
    }

}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    list.add(a);
}
```

Comment: Why are you new the list each time in jButton2 method ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to place addition of `list.toString` in a loop for every element of `list` as you are doing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
   jLabel1.setText(list.toString());
}
```

The above loop should be simply replaced by

```
jLabel1.setText(list.toString());
```

This will add all the contents of `list` to the `jLabel1`

**Why are you getting only the last element?**
As you are creating a new `ArrayList` every time in method `jButton2ActionPerformed`, and subsequently adding only one element to this newly created list, you get only the last element in your `jLabel1`

You need to have a list that is created only **once** (initialized only **once**) and each call of the `jButton2ActionPerformed` should `add` element to the existing list (instead of creating a new every time).

Answer (score 1):

Your code to set the text of the `JLabel` to a text containing all the contents of the list is correct. If only one number is displayed it’s either because the label is too small or because the list only contains one number.

You don’t need the `for` loop though, since `list.toString()` generates a string with all contents even when you just call it once. But it should work with multiple calls too, that is, with the `for` loop.

Your issue is that you’re creating a new list for each button press. This causes you to lose all contents of the previous list and only keep the new number added. So just don’t do that. Create the list once when your program starts, or when it’s appropriate.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, great minds think alike :) But I'd rather call me a beginner ;)